# Rediscovering euqation of line

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

I am studying (self learner) linear equations/equation of line and my idea is to discover the equations myself rather than try and understand ready-made equations available in text books. I am using X-Y Cartesian plane, with 2 points A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2). I know linear equations describe the relation between two points in my case Point A and Point B. So I was wondering if I come up with a definition in words and more Importantly as an Algebraic Equation; How can I make sure that my equation describes the relation Fully/Completely?! Is there a method/procedure to do this?! Also other than "completeness", are there other things/parameters a definition/description/equation is supposed to fulfill?

In addition to explaining it, any pointers, or links to relevant content are also hugely welcome.

Thanks much in Advance...

Comment: You'll need to start with a definition.  How are you defining the set of points you want to find an equation for?

Comment: @Piita My line of thought was that since X-Y plane has 2 degrees of freedom or 2 dimensions, namely x and y coordinates, if my definition included both of those then it would be complete or completely describe the relation. Am I right in thinking that?

Comment: @lulu good suggestion, in my opnion a point can be described by a set of unique values of x and y since the context or background is x-y plane.

Comment: Ok, and what's a line?

Comment: The problem is that how would you define what a line is? You end up resorting to using those equations.

Comment: @lulu I am still working on the definition of line. I am thinking do I describe it as if I am point A and then look at point B and describe it or I maybe I am point C looking at bothe Point A and B and describing it. Not sure right now...

Answer (score 1):

Finally this is what I could work out. Two points belong to a particular non-vertical line if they satisfy this equation:

`y1-c/x1 = y2-c/x2`

where c is y-intercept. So what I found out was that not only a point should have a same slope with respect to another point to point to belong to a line but even a single point's `y` and `x` sould have same ratio with respect to y-intercept for them to belong to a particular line.

I will work on more formal-rigorous definition and proof for the same.